# I have got this error in my php while insering data into database

Tags: php, sql, html

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'INTO' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\DB\info.php on line 18**

```
<?php 
     $servername = "localhost";  
     $username = "root";  
     $password = "";  
     $conn = mysql_connect ($servername , $username , $password)     or     die("unable to connect to host");  
     $sql = mysql_select_db ('vcet',$conn) or die("unable to connect to database"); 

     //code to insert into db...change the ussername and eamil to the     respective fields in the form....
     $user_info = "INSERT INTO studentinfo (user_name, roll_number,user_batch,user_from,user_year, user_level,F_name,m_name,
                    g_name,mob_number,addressline1, addressline2, city, pmob_number, land_number, cutoff, dept, medium, locality,
                    intrest, scholar, income, user_caste, user_admit, user_stay) 
                    VALUES ('$_POST[user_name]', '$_POST[roll_number]','$_POST[user_batch]','$_POST[user_from]','$_POST[user_year]',
                    '$_POST[user_level]','$_POST[F_name]','$_POST[m_name]','$_POST[g_name]','$_POST[mob_number]','$_POST[addressline1]',
                    '$_POST[addressline2]','$_POST[city]','$_POST[pmob_number]','$_POST[land_number]','$_POST[cutoff]','$_POST[dept]',
                    '$_POST[medium]','$_POST[locality]','$_POST[intrest]','$_POST[scholar]','$_POST[income]',
                    '$_POST[user_caste]','$_POST[user_admit]','$_POST[user_stay]',)"; 
     if (!mysql_query($user_info, $conn))
        {   
            die('Error: ' .     mysql_error()); 
        } 
     echo "Your information was added to the database."; 
     mysql_close($conn); 
 ?>
```

Comment: them quotes look kind of funny

Comment: Remove '$sql =' on 'mysql_select_db' it is not needed. You can also move the database name as another parameter to 'mysql_connect'

Answer (score 0):

first of all you don't have double quotes or single quotes instead you got “ which is not acceptable in php replace them by double qotes " and you will be fine

Comment: your 2nd point is wrong

Comment: no it's not 

this will give you an error

$array = array('hey' => 'ahmad');
echo "$array['hey']";

Comment: that will, but its NOT what he is doing

Comment: ok i checked and your opinion is right i edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

It's right query

```
$user_info = "INSERT INTO studentinfo (user_name, roll_number,     user_batch,user_from,user_year, user_level, F_name, m_name, g_name,     mob_number, addressline1, addressline2, city, pmob_number, land_number, cutoff, dept, medium, locality, intrest, scholar, income, user_caste, user_admit, user_stay) VALUES ('$_POST[user_name]', '$_POST[roll_number]','$_POST[user_batch]','$_POST[user_from]','$_POST[user_year]','$_POST[user_level]','$_POST[F_name]','$_POST[m_name]','$_POST[g_name]','$_POST[mob_number]','$_POST[addressline1]','$_POST[addressline2]','$_POST[city]','$_POST[pmob_number]','$_POST[land_number]','$_POST[cutoff]','$_POST[dept]','$_POST[medium]','$_POST[locality]','$_POST[intrest]','$_POST[scholar]','$_POST[income]','$_POST[user_caste]','$_POST[user_admit]','$_POST[user_stay]')";
```

Try to use " (double quoted) and remove your last comma in end of query

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'information' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\DB\info.php on line 19

Comment: replace this line echo “Your information was added to the database”;
with this

echo "Your information was added to the database";